# iOS8 extension NSItemProvider UIImage to ALAsset via ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: ios, uiimage, ios8, alassetslibrary, ios8-extension

I have a share extension that supports images.
Everything is working and I get the image from the item provider like so:

```
if([imageItemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
{
    [imageItemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage options:nil completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error)
     {
         if(image)
         {
             // do smth with the image here
         }
     }];
}
```

The issue is I'd like to access the image info via ALAssetsLibrary, and I don't have its URL since the loadItemForTypeIdentifier returns an UIImage directly. Any idea how to grab the image URL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change `[imageItemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage options:nil completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error)`

to

`[imageItemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage options:nil completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error)`

Notice the completion handler argument type. This will return to you the url that you are looking for.

Comment: Ok this is crazy magical. When I first saw this I thought no way but it was uprooted, and the documentation confirms this as does using it. They're either doing some runtime inspection on the block or compiler voodoo.

Comment: It's really cool! That's for sure, but not hard to implement. [Introspection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Introspection/Introspection.html) by way of [NSObject isKindOfClass:] is one such solution.